# NHibernate / FluentNHibernate readonly compositeId

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map 2 entities.

**JournalEntry.cs**

```
class JournalEntry
{
    private readonly IList<JournalEntryItem> _items;

    public JournalEntry()
    {
        _items = new List<JournalEntryItem>();
    }

    public IList<JournalEntryItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

**JournalEntryItem.cs**

```
class JournalEntryItem
{
    private readonly JournalEntry _journalEntry;
    private readonly Account _account;

    public JournalEntryItem(JournalEntry journalEntry, Account account)
    {
        _journalEntry = journalEntry;
        _account = account;
    }

    public JournalEntry JournalEntry
    {
        get { return _journalEntry; }
    }

    public Account Account
    {
        get { return _account; }
    }
}
```

**JournalEntryItemMap.cs**

```
class JournalEntryItemMap : ClassMap<JournalEntryItem>
{
    public JournalEntryItem()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).Access.Field()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Account).Access.Field();

        // Tried this too, obviously won't work anyway
        // CompositeId()
        //    .KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).ReadOnly()
        //    .KeyReference(x => x.Account).ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

This mapping throws an exception :

`Could not find a setter for property 'JournalEntry' in class Macsauto.Domain.Accounting.Entities.JournalEntryItem'`

The only workaround I know of is to make a protected property.

Is there another workaround?

**Update**

Tried this but still not working:

**JournalEntryItemMap.cs**

```
class JournalEntryItemMap : ClassMap<JournalEntryItem>
{
    public JournalEntryItem()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(Reveal.Member<JournalEntryItem, JournalEntry>("_journalEntry")).Access.Field()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Account).Access.Field();
    }
}
```

**Update**
I tried a method from [FluentNHibernate wiki page](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-a-collection-that-uses-a-private-backing-field), but even that produces the same error.

**JournalEntryItem.cs**

```
class JournalEntryItem
{
    // Removed the _ prefix just to make it even more similar with
    // those on FluentNHibernate wiki page
    private readonly JournalEntry journalEntry;

    public JournalEntryItem(JournalEntry journalEntry)
    {
        this.journalEntry = journalEntry;
    }

    public JournalEntry JournalEntry
    {
        get { return journalEntry; }
    }
}
```

**JournalEntryItemMap.cs**

```
class JournalEntryItemMap : ClassMap<JournalEntryItem>
{
    public JournalEntryItem()
    {
        CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).Access.CamelCaseField();

        // Other tried combinations, all throws same no setter error
        // CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField();
        // CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).Access.LowerCaseField();
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting curious, does it have to do with version issue?

I uses NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 and FluentNHibernate 1.4.0.0.

Does FluentNHibernate keep up with NHibernate? It's almost like NHibernate ignores any access type mapping I wrote in FluentNHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `CamelCaseField()` access:

```
CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry).Access.CamelCaseField()
             .KeyReference(x => x.Account).Access.CamelCaseField();
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) about mapping strategies.

Comment: Don't you have a empty constructor? NHibernate need a empty constructor to get your entities working. Try to add a `public` or `protected` empty constructor.

Comment: Hi I'm accepting your answer since it leads me to the right direction, but I found out the problem in my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I feel silly for not reading through the comments on KeyReference method.

Here's how it works for compositeId :

```
public class JournalEntryItemMap : ClassMap<JournalEntryItem>
{
    public JournalEntryItemMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.JournalEntry, map => map.Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore));
    }
}
```

Notice the access setting is inside the KeyReference method.